# How to destroy a class object in PHP?

Tags: php, class, object, destroy

I wrote a little class for storing global variables/functions. My question is - is it necessary to destroy the class object after the script has finished?
or will PHP destroy that object itself?

Here's my code:

```
$web=new c_web("myWeb");
$web->loadTemplate("/!framework/admin/template.htm");
$web->doStuff();
// script has finished - destroying required here?
```

In case I need to destroy it, how can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the script finishes, the memory is released. You're ready as is :)

Comment: great - thanks! and what about if a script will will be terminated by an error? will all variables (database ..) be destroyed aswell?

Comment: Well, the database connection might need a 'close', but in most situations you only need to worry about this when you need more memory DURING exection. So if you load X amount of data in an object, and then you want to do it again. But basically: don't worry, code happy :)

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not need to destroy any variable yourself *(and an object is a variable)* : as soon as your PHP script reaches its end, its variables will be freed, and the correspondig memory released.

Actually, a variable gets destroyed automatically when the end of its [**variable's scope**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) is reached -- and, when you reach end of script, it's the end of the scope introduced by that script's execution.

*(Answering a comment to another answer)*

Of course, when your script is ended because of an error, the same thing happens : the variables are freed, and the memory released.

Comment: what about open database connections? do i need to close them at all?

Comment: Unless you're using persistent connections, connections are automatically terminated when the PHP script ends.

Answer (score 4):

As @Nanne sayd, if the script finished the memory is released, however in some circumstances you might whant to [unset($web);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) .